# Функция Аккермана c#

Tags: c#, функции, рекурсия

Помогите разобраться в чем ошибка?

```
static int S(int n, int m)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return m + 1;
    else if (n > 0 && m == 0)
        return S(n - 1, 1);
    else if (n > 0 && m > 0)
        return S(n - 1, S(n, m - 1));
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int k;
    k = S(9, 2); 
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

В первой строке выдает ошибку "не все пути к коду возвращают значение"

Comment: А что вам непонятно во фразе "не все пути к коду возвращают значение"? Если ни один `if` не сработает, функция ничего не вернёт, а должна вернуть `int`. Например, в случае `n < 0`. Вы такое `n` не собираетесь передавать в функцию, но компилятор то об этом не знает, с его точки зрения функция не является корректной.